# When should I use a Column Family NoSQL solution vs Key-Value, Document Store, Graph

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra, riak

I understand the technical differences between the different solutions. But I can't seem to find concrete examples of the pros/cons of the different types of NoSQL solutions, and when to use one type over the other.

All of the information I find online gives very vague suggestions of when to use one type vs the other. And they all seem to be able to be interchangeably used without a clear indication of the advantage of using one over the other.

Answer (score 5):

### Document-oriented

**Examples:** MongoDB, CouchDB

**Strengths:** Heterogenous data, working object-oriented, agile development

Their advantage is that they do not require a consistent data structure. They are useful when your requirements and thus your database layout changes constantly, or when you are dealing with datasets which belong together but still look very differently. When you have a lot of tables with two columns called "key" and "value", then these might be worth looking into.

### Graph databases

**Examples:** Neo4j, GiraffeDB

**Strengths:** Data Mining

Their focus is at defining data by its relation to other data. When you have a lot of tables with primary keys which are the primary keys of two other tables (and maybe some data describing the relation between them), then these might be something for you.

### Key-Value Stores

**Examples:** Redis, Cassandra, MemcacheDB

**Strengths:** Fast lookup of values by known keys

They are very simplistic, but that makes them fast and easy to use. When you have no need for stored procedures, constraints, triggers and all those advanced database features and you just want fast storage and retrieval of your data, then those are for you.

Unfortunately they assume that you know exactly what you are looking for. You need the profile of User157641? No problem, will only take microseconds. But what when you want the names of all users who are aged between 16 and 24, have "waffles" as their favorite food and logged in in the last 24 hours? Tough luck. When you don't have a definite and unique key for a specific result, you can't get it out of your K-V store that easily.

Comment: Isn't Cassandra a Column family store? (asking this since many might have the same question)

Answer (score 4):

There is an excellent article describing the types of nosql databases and when to use what.. read [this](http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/nosql-databases-overview)

You will get a good understanding.